# Chosen result from Worksheet cell to Userform Combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I have Userform that have combobox. Combobox picks range from Workbook and inputs picked up result to cell C79 by this VBA:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Other Data").Range("C79").Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

The problem is when I open Userform for the second time I can't see picked up result in combobox so I have to pick it up again. How to link cell C79 to `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` so that when I open UserForm, value from C79 will be visible in Combobox1?

I have tried:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.List = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("A79:A81").Value ' This one picks the range
    'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("C79").Value = ReviewForm.ComboBox1.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Of course it has to be the other way round: `ReviewForm.ComboBox1.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("C79").Value` if you want to write the cell value into the combo box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To populate a ComboBox control in a UserForm, use the following

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.ComboBox1.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("C97").Value
End Sub
```

Alternatively, you could update this value each time the UF is activated:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Me.ComboBox1.Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Other Data").Range("C97").Value
End Sub
```

Or, you could update the UF's combobox every time the cell value changes. This is not logical however, since you update the cell with the UF. It would activate itself.